# How do I know if a guard rejected a transistion

Tags: spring-statemachine

I have transitions configured as in the [reference documentation:](http://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#sm-guards)

```
public void configure(StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<States, Events> transitions)
        throws Exception {
    transitions
        .withExternal()
            .source(States.SI).target(States.S1)
            .event(Events.E1)
            .guard(guard1())
            .and()
        .withExternal()
            .source(States.S1).target(States.S2)
            .event(Events.E1)
            .guard(guard2())
            .and()
        .withExternal()
            .source(States.S2).target(States.S3)
            .event(Events.E2)
            .guardExpression("extendedState.variables.get('myvar')");
}
```

If the state machine is in state `States.S1` and I send event `Events.E1`, how do I know if `guard2()` rejected the transition?

I'm currently checking the state of the state machine: if it's still in `States.S1` then I know the event was rejected.  Is this the "right" way to handle rejection by a guard?

Edit:

After reading Janne's comment I realized what I'm trying to do is probably an incorrect use of a guard.  It seems that guards should be used only to determine which state the machine should transition to and not whether or not a state should be entered.  If it was the latter, i.e. the transition was outright rejected, then the state machine would be in no state. I should have been tipped off by what the code allows me to do and by having a state machine-centric mindset when coding the workflow. That's what I get for rushing before a holiday!

Comment: I don't think we have any specific hooks to get notified about these things. Maybe by creating custom `Guard` implementations and then hook to those manually. You are first one to ask things like this. Could you elaborate what you are trying to accomplish with this?  Just asking because maybe there is better way to do what is your goal here.

Comment: @JanneValkealahti, I realized what I was trying to do was the wrong way to go about it, that instead I should transition to another state. The reference guide says, "Guards are used to protect state transitions"...perhaps it should also say (if this is indeed correct) that they should only be used with choice/junction pseudostates.

Comment: However, stating that guards should only be used with choice/junction pseudostates is apparently not correct because that's not how the example code is written.  What happens in the example code if `guard2()` returns `false`? The state machine remains in `S1` and then what?

Comment: Not all possible use-cases make sense what you can do in theory. But for example check statechart in github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/issues/240. `errorGuard` protects anonymous transition from parent `LAUNCHTASK` so that if any action adds exception to extended state variables, machine is taken into `ERROR` state automatically.

Comment: Thanks @JanneValkealahti. If you make your comment an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I'm facing a similar dilema. Before transitioning from StateA to StateB I would also like to check if the input provided with the event is what I expect. I was using the guard approach but I also need to return an appropriate response to the caller. The question is: how can I ensure that the guard validation failed? I've also tried throwing an exception from the actions does not seem to bubble up to my controller advice @JanneValkealahti