# Spring StateMachine How do I know if a transistion is rejected due to failed guard or action?

Tags: java, architecture, event-driven, spring-statemachine

I have the same question as in the topic below, but I'm not so sure if my approach is wrong.

[How do I know if a guard rejected a transistion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41305495/how-do-i-know-if-a-guard-rejected-a-transistion/67138112#67138112)

My app is a linear step-by-step strategy board game with several different game settings. I've decided to use Spring StateMachine to solve as in my opinion (and so far) it solves a lot little code-related organisational problems But now I'm stacked

The problem I have run into is that I can't say if my event passed all the guards and transition occurs. I just get true-flag when an event is added to the queue

The approach I'm following is passing data via `event-context`, validation of one with guards and apply changes using actions

```
        transitions
            .withExternal().source(SPEECHES).target(VOTING).event(VOTING_EVENT)
            .guard(Guard.and(
                    guards.get(NoVotesFromSuspectedGuard.QUALIFIER),
                    guards.get(NoSelfVotingGuard.QUALIFIER),
                    guards.get(NoDeadParticipantsVotingGuard.QUALIFIER),
                    guards.get(NoVotingForDeadParticipantsGuard.QUALIFIER),
                    votingOutOfParticipantListGuardFactory.get(NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS),
                    guards.get(VotingBasedOnPreviousOneGuard.QUALIFIER)
            ))
            .action(actions.get(CalculateVotingAction.QUALIFIER))
```

As I understand now, there is no possibility to notify `event-supplier` about failed guard evaluation. If so, just let me know and I will switch to another SM implementation. But if there is any possibility of solving my problem, please help me.

The behaviour I expect is any meta info of failed guard (to build formatted error message)

Answer (score 0):

You can use some context flag, for example `context.put("NoVotesFromSuspectedGuard", false)` when "NoVotesFromSuspectedGuard" isn't `success` and then you can check this variable in your invoke code `context.getExternalVariables().get("NoVotesFromSuspectedGuard", Boolean.class)`.
Also, in Spring State Machine you can declare ActionListener bean, which contains some different methods for StateMachine events monitoring.

For more information, you can see [Habr](https://habr.com/ru/post/462371/)(Russian)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your idea. But this one seems not a really good approach to me. I would rather like to switch to FSM with synchronised  execution than to handle this case by external vars and hanging the request till all the async calls get finished with some result (to put one in the vars)